# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.security.permission.AbstractNameSetOnlyPermission

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I am testing jax-rs web services with Arquillian, and I use an embedded Wildfly 10 container. This is my pom.xml:

```
..  
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
    <!--<version>2.1.0.Final</version> -->
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

..

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- You need the maven dependency plugin to download locally a zip with 
            the server, unless you provide your own, it will download under the /target 
            directory -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Fork every test because it will launch a separate AS instance -->
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

..
with arquillian.xml in src/test/resources:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<container qualifier="wildfly10" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">target/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/</property>
        <property name="modulePath">target/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

..
But when type: ***mvn clean verify***, I get the following error:
***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.security.permission.AbstractNameSetOnlyPermission***

Comment: More notes than anything because I couldn't seem to replicate this issue. The `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-embedded` dependency should not be needed. Also the `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded` should be marked as `<scope>test</scope>`/

Comment: Also running into this on a simple project.

Comment: FWIW, here's [the jira with a workaround](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9747)